# Gettings started entity framework database development (code first)

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first

Are there any heavy drawbacks of creating databases with entityframework using the **code first** approach regarding the fact that the goal is Azure? I know little about Azure (yet :)) but I know I will pay per transaction.

So now I am a bit worried, if I do not have to bother writing SQL statements by hand, will entity framework code first still generate "cost-friendly" SQL mappings for me? Or is code first a bad practice when it comes to Azure database?

Comment: Azure SQL Database's cost doesn't operate based on transactions unlike Azure Storage Table. (
Azure Storage Table : Data Size + Transaction Count + Out BandWidth,
Azure SQL Databases : Data Size + Out BandWidth )

Comment: Ah that's a good point. I just checked the online calculator and you're right (not that I doubted you :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure SQL Database's cost doesn't operate based on transactions unlike Azure Storage Table.

`Azure Storage Table` : Data Size + Transaction Count + Out BandWidth

`Azure SQL Databases` : Data Size + Out BandWidth